# ERROR when sending message to topic in Kafka windows

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a problem to send a message to my topic "MCHVAS".
I used tyhis command:

```
kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic MCHVAS
>mamma mia`
```

and the result is:

> [2023-09-24 14:06:17,510] ERROR Error when sending message to topic MCHVAS with key: null, value: 9 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for MCHVAS-0:120012 ms has passed since batch creation

I control my server properties in config folder of kafka and the configuration is:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

the topic MCHVAS was created, the result is this:

```
C:\Apache\kafka_2.13-3.5.1\bin\windows>kafka-topics.bat --describe --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic MCHVAS
Topic: MCHVAS   TopicId: 2TMVGbecTdq3SuR-kK6R8A 
PartitionCount: 1       
ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs:
    Topic: MCHVAS   Partition: 0    Leader: none    Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
```

and this:

```
C:\Apache\kafka_2.13-3.5.1\bin\windows>kafka-topics.bat --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
MCHVAS
__consumer_offsets
```

Answer (score 0):

Expiring producer batches is expected behavior when you're sending less than `batch.size` bytes in any request.

If you only want to send one (small) record, it's better to use shell redirection to pipe into the console producer

```
echo "mamma mia" > kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic MCHVAS
```

Otherwise, you need to close the producer very shortly after the input prompt to close and **flush** the producer buffer. When you write a non cli producer, you'll want to make sure you're also flushing there

Comment: After the producer is opened, 
     kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic MCHVAS
I see a > sign.
Then any line of text I write afterwards will be sent to the Kafka topic (when pressing Enter)

Comment: No, it won't. It'll be sent to a memory buffer, then will expire if producer buffer is not flushed, and return the error you're getting. Only a successful buffer flush will actually make a network request to a broker